# If $f$ is differentiable and $f'\geq m\geq0$, $|\int_a^b\cos{f(x)}dx|\leq2/m$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, self-learning

> Suppose $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is a differentiable function such that its derivative is monotonically decreasing and $f'(x)\geq m>0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Prove that $$|\int_a^b\cos f(x)dx|\leq\dfrac{2}{m}$$

I am having some problem with manipulating the modulus and the integral such that I can take $\dfrac{1}{f'(x)}\leq\dfrac{1}{m}$ out. That is, I was thinking about writing it as follows:

> Take $f(x)=z$. Then $f'(x)dx=dz$.

However, I am not quite sure if I can do this because I am not given that $f'$ is also continuous, and change of variable will not work if $f$ is not continuously differentiable. Also, even if I suppose I **can** do this, I am not quite sure how to proceed. Also, I fail to see why we need the monotonic decreasing property of the derivative.

Some hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Since $f'(x) \ge m > 0$, we have $$\int_a^b \cos f(x)\, dx = \int_a^b \frac{1}{f'(x)}f'(x)\cos f(x)\, dx = \int_a^b \frac{1}{f'(x)}\frac{d}{dx}(\sin f(x))\, dx.$$  Since $f'$ is monotonic decreasing and positive, by the Bonnet mean value theorem for integrals, $$\int_a^b \frac{1}{f'(x)} \frac{d}{dx}(\sin f(x))\, dx = \frac{1}{f'(b)}\int_c^b \frac{d}{dx}(\sin f(x))\, dx = \frac{\sin f(b) - \sin f(c)}{f'(b)}$$ for some $c\in [a,b]$. Therefore, $$\left|\int_a^b \cos f(x)\, dx\right| = \frac{|\sin f(b) - \sin f(c)|}{f'(b)} \le \frac{|\sin f(b)| + |\sin f(c)|}{m} \le \frac{2}{m}.$$

Comment: $f'$ is not necessarily continuous. Can we still use the mean value theorem?

Comment: @yedaynara sorry, I was in the middle of an edit. I meant to use the second mean value theorem for integrals, rather than the first.

Comment: What I know is that $p,g$ must be both continuous if I am to write $\int pg=p(c)\int g$ for some $c$ in the domain. Also, $g$ cannot change sign. How are you sure that $\sin f(x)$ does not change sign? And how are you sure that $f'$ is continuous? Because otherwise, you can't write it.

Comment: @yedaynara  look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), down to the section "Second Mean Value Theorem for Integration".

Comment: @yedaynara I'll make another edit.

Comment: This is interesting. For the second mean value theorem also, I knew that both functions have to be continuous. It seems we were not taught this!! Thank you. I stand corrected then.

Comment: I do not mean to doubt Wikipedia but I am not really sure that our Professor will not teach this. I found an alternative form of 2nd Mean Value Theorem on Wiki which relaxes the condition on a function $G$ to being just monotonic instead of continuous, while our professor gave us the statement of the theorem including continuity. Our professor is a great man of Analysis and I doubt he would be careless about this. Incidentally, many other sites I visited also impose continuity. Nowhere is it mentioned that the result relies on monotonicity singly.

Comment: @yedaynara perhaps you've missed that if $g$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, then the integral $\int_a^x g(t)\, dt$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. This is what is used in proofs of the these mean value theorems. In any case, look [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=UXbzq3y4pRkC&pg=PP11&lpg=PP11&dq=generalization+of+Bonnet%27s+mean+value+theorem&source=bl&ots=N3Cx-QJZUq&sig=sCMvdTq1uTXPo7CqB7MGZ7sH8EE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UZ7bVOnsHMGcygT2sYHABw&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=generalization%20of%20Bonnet's%20mean%20value%20theorem&f=false) and scroll down to page 51.

Comment: The Bonnet mean value theorem is the version of the second mean value theorem that is being used in my post.